# Unsupported OS - I am trying to run Docker push Buildinfo in Windows machine but its get failed for Unsupported OS

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

```
node("DevHub && WinServer2019"){
    cleanWs()

    stage ("in windows docker") {
        withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: "ABC_Technical_User", url: "https://abc-swc-build-toolchains-docker-dev") {
            dockerImage = docker.image("abc-swc-build-toolchains-docker-dev/ci-snapshot/mt4/windows_vc100:image-13-77d3d3b")
            dockerImage.pull()
            String rtDocker = ''
        
            def server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'https://abc/artifactory/', credentialsId: 'ABC_Technical_User'
            def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
    // Step 2: Create an Artifactory Docker instance:
             def bdDocker = Artifactory.docker server: server
             
         
             buildInfo localBuildInfo = bdDocker.pull 'abc-swc-build-toolchains-docker-dev/ci-snapshot/mt4/windows_vc100:base-image-13-77d3d3b', 'abc-swc-build-toolchains-docker-dev'
            // Step 4: Publish the build-info to Artifactory:
               buildInfo.append localBuildInfo
               echo "buildInfo : ${buildInfo}"
               server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
        }
       
    }
}
```

I am getting below error

```
INFO: Pulling image: abc-swc-build-toolchains-docker-dev/ci-snapshot/mt4/windows_vc100:base-image-13-77d3d3b
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported OS**
    at com.github.dockerjava.netty.NettyDockerCmdExecFactory$UnixDomainSocketInitializer.init(NettyDockerCmdExecFactory.java:147)
    at com.github.dockerjava.netty.NettyDockerCmdExecFactory.init(NettyDockerCmdExecFactory.java:116)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientImpl.withDockerCmdExecFactory(DockerClientImpl.java:193)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder.build(DockerClientBuilder.java:45)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.docker.DockerJavaWrapper.getDockerClient(DockerJavaWrapper.java:77)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.docker.DockerJavaWrapper.pullImage(DockerJavaWrapper.java:150)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.docker.extractor.DockerPull.execute(DockerPull.java:76)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.packageManager.PackageManagerExtractor.executeAndSaveBuildInfo(PackageManagerExtractor.java:33)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.docker.extractor.DockerPull.main(DockerPull.java:61)

java.lang.RuntimeException: docker build failed
```

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to test the scenario with the latest [Jenkins Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in) and Java 11? I remember a similar issue reported in the past due to a lower Java version/old plugin as well. Upgrading the plugin to the latest version along with the respective Java version mentioned, should help in resolving the issue.